# R report as pdf (LaTeX beamer): table does not fit on slide

Tags: r, latex, beamer

I'm creating a 6x6 matrix as part of my R report (output as `beamer_presentation`). Unfortunately, it exceeds my slide width; it looks like this:

[image]

I tried to put a LaTeX command around the R block in my .Rmd file, but all it did was destroying the table/`knitr::kable` layout. This is the block in question:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
[... create correlation matrix ...]
knitr::kable(correlations, digits = 4)
```
````

How can I resize this table so it fits my slide?

Comment: If you are writing this in Latex, before your R block add the line, `\small`, then afterward, add the line `\normalsize` and see if this does the trick.

Comment: It's a tad better, I can see the first digit of the cut-off column in the picture I uploaded. Still missing the rest and a whole other column though.

Comment: There are other sizes  such as `vsmall` and `\tiny`. If these don't work, you may have to use `\parbox` to control the width of your columns. This is something to be avoided if possible and I'm not sure that it is possible with `kable`.

Comment: It works with `\tiny`, thanks.